# Jenkins - ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [255]]

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to send a file over ssh but i encountered the below error.

*SSH: Connecting from host [host]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [server] ...
SSH: EXEC: completed after 201 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [server] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [255]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: UNSTABLE*

Answer (score 0):

[SSH exit code 255](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) is a generic "something went wrong" so you'll need to provide more information in order for anyone to be able to help you.

- Are you using an SSH plugin or linux ssh command?
- Does your command work locally outside of jenkins?
- Are there any firewalls involved?
- How are you passing Jenkins your ssh credentials?